# Combine Beginning Unallocated Space with Ending Ubuntu Partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, kubuntu, gparted, mountpoint

I couldn't find an example anywhere of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Below is what my hard drive looks like right now.
I want to either:

1. Combine the unallocated space at the beginning of the drive with my kubuntu install on sda3
2. Or at least make the unallocated space available to use as extra storage for my kubuntu OS

[image: Gparted image of my HDD]

I'm afraid that if I resize sda3 to take up the unallocated space, it will screw up my linux mount point, resulting in frustrating problems. Perhaps I just need to reassign the mount point after resizing?

I would also settle for just being able to use that unallocated space to store documents and other files.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd just grow sda3 using the unallocated space before it, and ignore the unallocated at the end of the drive.  If you have sda3 mounted (ie. running) `gparted` will no doubt complain (you need to umount first), so I'd just use a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) to do the resize. At worst you'll lose the pointer from grub stage1 (mbr) that points to where in sda3 the /boot (grub stage1.5) is, but its easily fixed (and most likely won't be an issue anyway)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just do it.  The partition table will still list the expanded one as Partition 3, and you will have no Partition 1.  I have done this myself.